# Jenkins WebSphere Deployer Plugin Error

Tags: jenkins, websphere

I tried to deploy .war file to web sphere application server from my jenkins 
I followed following steps which mentioned in

[https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+WebSphere+Configuration][1]

My **Test Connection is successfull**

```
But I got following exception 
Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server:        org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.DeploymentServiceException:   Failed to install artifact: Failure uploading archive to server
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.installArtifact(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:251)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.deployArtifact(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:227)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:201)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)

Build step 'Deploy To IBM WebSphere Application Server' changed build result to FAILURE
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE


  [1]: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+WebSphere+Configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SOAP connector via the WebSphere Deployer Plugin, you may run into this issue of you're uploading large EAR files that take longer than 3 minutes to deploy. Try the following.

For the WebSphere instances you are deploying to, change the following setting in each file to a higher timeout setting.

[WAS Install]/profiles/[profile]/properties/soap.client.properties

com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout=180 (Change this setting to 600 or higher)

A restart of WAS will likely be required to this setting change. Hope this helps you!

-The WDP Architect